# selenium get span text loaded with ajax

Tags: ajax, selenium

I have a price which loaded with Ajax and displayed in span. Certainly in Html is it hardcoded price 0. But on the page I see a new Price. And it's always the same problem: my Test doesn't see the price, which I get with Ajax request.

```
public void testSW40RolladenwelleKonfi() {
    System.out.println("test preis SW40 Ausfuehrung Rolladenwelle Konfi");
    driver.get("https://");
    WebElement lange = driver.findElement(By.id("txt_sw_laenge"));
    lange.clear();
    lange.sendKeys("1000");
    WebElement sw40 = driver.findElement(By.id("SW40"));
    sw40.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
     Boolean element =   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@id='productprice']/text()"), "10,00"));
assertTrue(element);
}
```

I had also tried:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until( 
  ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/span[@id='productprice']")));
assertEquals(element.getText(), "10,00");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the /text() from your webdriver wait condition. Use below and check...

```
Boolean element =   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@id='productprice']"), "10,00"));
```

Comment: I get this Answer every time: Expected condition failed: waiting for text ('10,00') to be present in element found by By.xpath: //span[@id='productprice'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Can you share the html page source after the ajax call is completed.

Comment: It's before:  <span style="text-decoration: underline;font-size:24px;"><b><span id="productprice" class="productprice">0.00</span> &euro;</b></span>

Comment: After: 
 <span style="text-decoration: underline;font-size:24px;"><b><span class="productprice" id="productprice">10.00</span> €</b></span>

ajax Parameter
falz aussen
laenge 1000
preis  10.00
sw 40
verstaerkt nein

and get an Answer: 
10

Comment: The value you should be comparing with is 10.00 instead of 10,00 that you are currently using. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually locating [`text()` node doesn't work with selenium `WebDriver` `WebElement`](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5459).

Your xpath doesn't return an element; it returns a text node. While this might have been perfectly acceptable in `Selenium RC` (and by extension, `Selenium IDE`), **the methods on the `WebDriver` `WebElement` interface require an element object, not just any DOM node object.**

To fix this issue you should use `//span[@id='productprice']` xpath instead, but here no need to use xpath, You can try using `By.id()` as below :-

```
Boolean element =   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("productprice"), "10,00"));
assertTrue(element);
```